# Rails wrapbootstrap template less parse error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I have purchased a wrapbootstrap template and now I have problem to apply it to my project in Ruby on Rails. All js and css files I insert into /vendor/assets and in /app/assets/stylesheets/appplication.css I've inserted this line

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/stylesheets/.
```

The same I've done in /app/assets/javascript/application.js

```
*= require_tree ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts/.
```

My Gemfile is

```
gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'table_print'
gem 'devise'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'therubyracer'
gem 'less-rails'
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'   

gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'less-rails-bootstrap', '~> 3.2.0'

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin]
```

Finally I'm getting a 
**Less::ParseError in Home#index**

variable @enable-navbar-dropdowns is undefined
  (in /home/james/Desktop/SP2/frontend_v2/vendor/assets/stylesheets/less/ace-nav.less)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj3LH.png

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

This is my worked application.css

```
*= require ace/bootstrap/bootstrap
*= require ace/ace
*= require_self
```

* Note that I removed `require tree .`